# Is it possible to open Hotspot while we are using wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

I have tried but you can only use one at a time either WiFi or Hotspot but it'll be great if we can use hotspot while we are using WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Its not possible.

Creating a WiFi Hotspot **requires** using the WiFi interface. And the interface, at the moment, supports using it for one thing at a time, either connecting to a Router with it, OR, creating a hotspot (router) for others to connect to.

As a side note, it would have even been nice to have your phone to connect two WiFis for faster browser. But that's also not possible either, *at the moment*.

Comment: WiFi and Hotspot at the same time is possible for certain WLAN adapters on PC, though.

Comment: @NVZ *on PC* yep. But phones, I'm yet to hear of any that supports that!